# SSRS - Matrix Report with Only Text Fields (SSRS automatically converting it to Tablix)

Tags: ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, reporting-services

I am trying to create a matrix report in SSRS  but the problem is that there are no measures in my report,just text fields. So when I pull the Matrix template from the toolbox and drag in the report fields, SSRS automatically converts it to a Tablix report. Is there any way I can force SSRS to stick to Matrix report?

Answer (score 0):

Tablix is the common name for both Table and Matrix. According to Microsoft, it stands for Table + Matrix (**Tabl** + **ix**).

Can you click on your control, see if it still has both Row Groups and Column Groups? If it does, the control is still a Matrix.

Comment: Thanks Cam , I figured it out that its still a Matrix report even though it looks like Table.It does have row and column groups